# How to check whether an two dimensional array present in a List?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist

I have two list of two dimensional array

```
List<double[,]>list1=new List<double[4,4]>();
List<double[,]>list2=new List<double[4,4]>();
```

The length of lists are not necessarily equal.

Answer (score 1):

What you have does not work because `Contains` will do a reference comparison to check equality when iterating the list. Unless your 2d arrays in each list refer to the same object reference, even if they're semantically the same it would not identify them as being equal.

For example, in this case the match would be found:

```
var my2d = new double[2, 2] { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 } };            
List<double[,]> list1 = new List<double[,]>() { my2d };
List<double[,]> list2 = new List<double[,]>() { my2d };

foreach (var matrix in list1)
    if (list2.Contains(matrix)) 
        Console.WriteLine("FOUND!");
```

But if we change the lists to have separate instances of the 2d array, it would not:

```
List<double[,]> list1 = new List<double[,]>() { new double[2, 2] { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 } } };
List<double[,]> list2 = new List<double[,]>() { new double[2, 2] { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 } } };
```

One way you could overcome this is to specify your own `IEqualityComparer` to tell the `Contains` method how to perform a comparison. For example, here is something that could compare a two dimension array element by element:

```
public class TwoDimensionCompare<T> : IEqualityComparer<T[,]>
{
    public bool Equals(T[,] x, T[,] y)
    {
        // fail fast if the sizes aren't the same
        if (y.GetLength(0) != x.GetLength(0)) return false;
        if (y.GetLength(1) != x.GetLength(1)) return false;
        // compare element by element
        for (int i = 0; i < y.GetLength(0); i++)
            for (int z = 0; z < y.GetLength(1); z++)
                if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x[i, z], y[i, z])) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T[,] obj)
    {
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
List<double[,]> list1 = new List<double[,]>() { new double[2, 2] { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 } } };
List<double[,]> list2 = new List<double[,]>() { new double[2, 2] { { 1, 3 }, { 3, 5 } } };

foreach (var matrix in list1)
    if (list2.Contains(matrix, new TwoDimensionCompare<double>())) 
        Console.WriteLine("FOUND!");
```